# Password recovery Htmlcontent is not working properly

Tags: sitecore-api

We have customized passwordrecovery pipeline. In the password recovery email, we are not getting the html content, instead we are getting the tags itself.

Sample mail content we recieved:

[image]
Below is the code snippet:

if (isHTML)
args.HtmlEmailContent = mailContent;

[image]
Is there any settings we need to change in the config.

Comment: Did you set the email message flag as html, in code? I am imagining you are sending your own email in the pipeline?

Comment: Yes we are sending our own email in the pipeline.

Comment: Can you add the code used to send the email please?

Answer (score 1):

The code we have written is working fine and we are receiving html content in email.
It is our bad, we forgot to put the else condition in the below code. That resolved our issue!!!.

if (isHTML)
                    args.HtmlEmailContent = mailContent;
                else
                    args.EmailContent = mailContent;